# Getiing error in remix while using oraclize

Tags: solidity, remix

Getting this error" called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance" even when i set value

[image]

Comment: What function are you calling? What parameters are you using?

Comment: I am calling update function

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
function _callback(bytes32 queryid, ....) payable
{
...
}
```

You just need to append the word `payable` to the function.

Comment: if i add payable to that function it was showing me     Overriding function changes state mutability from "nonpayable" to "payable".  this error

Answer (score 1):

You can't create oraclize-linked contract using "Javascript VM". Just because there is no oraclize contract there. Try to deploy the contract to the one of public testnets, for example, in Ropsten.